# Extract all words with a similar pattern from the same line and display them in a list

Tags: shell, unix

I have got an xml file that I have displayed using cat, and I have also piped through the grep command to extract the one line I am looking for.

The command looks like:

```
cat file_name.xml | grep -i pattern1
```

The output is one line long enclosed within xml brackets:

```
<list_of_names>ABC987599.com,ABC419192.com,ABC456321.com</list_of_names>
```

How do I manipulate this output so that I get the list of ABC addresses like so:

```
ABC987599.com

ABC419192.com

ABC456321.com
```

I have tried

```
cat file_name.xml | grep -i pattern1 | grep -Po 'ABC*com'
```

But all that gives me is

```
ABC

ABC

ABC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a simple translation from comma to newline, like in this example:

```
echo "a,b,c" | tr "," "\n"
a
b
c
```

Have fun :-)

**Edit:**
Obviously, you need to remove your XML tags first, I propose `sed` for this:

```
echo "<list_of_names>ABC987599.com,ABC419192.com,ABC456321.com</list_of_names>" 
  | sed 's/<list_of_names>//g' 
  | sed 's/<\/list_of_names>//g' 
  | tr "," "\n"
```

(The whole command with the pipes is to be put on one line.)

For your information: when working with a `/` character in `sed`, it must be preceded by a backslash, hence `<\/list...`.